# How to use the viewmodel with different types of projects

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, windows-phone, viewmodel

I have a rather complex project existing of multiple sub projects.

- Application

  - WPF Application
  - Windows Store App
  - Windows Phone App
- Contracts

  - Service Contract (WCF for WPF)
  - Service Controller (WebAPi for windows phone)
- Infrastructure (EventAggregator/Prism)
- ViewModels (Preferably usable by WPF, Windows Phone and Windows App)
- Views (WPF Specific)

As long I concentrate on WPF, I have no problems. In my viewmodel I can call the webservice and fill it with the required data. For Windows Phone/Windows Store App I can't always use WCF. However the viewmodel remains the same. How would I "send" the correct service call to my viewmodel?

```
public async override Task<object> RetrieveItems()
    {
        if ((Customer != null))
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => Current.ApplicationService.Schedule_Appointments_GetItems_By_Relation(Customer.Relation_ID));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This function works fine as long its a wcf service.
Is there some possibility to change this function depending on the view that uses this viewmodel?

Here's the full code of one viewmodel:

```
namespace ISynergy.Modules.Relations
{
public class Customer_Activities_ViewModel : Customer_Base_ViewModel
{

    public Customer_Activities_ViewModel()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void Add()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Task Delete(object vItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Edit(object vItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public async override Task<object> RetrieveItems()
    {
        if ((Customer != null))
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => Current.ApplicationService.Schedule_Appointments_GetItems_By_Relation(Customer.Relation_ID));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Of course the same applies to the other overridden procedures/functions (Add, Delete and Edit)

Comment: After some more investigation, maybe the answer lies in use of Func's and Action's...
I will try some stuff and get back to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got the answer.
I anyone has a suggestion or comment please be free to provide one.
Maybe this answer helps others with the same problem.

The solution consists of two adjustments.

```
public async override Task<object> RetrieveItems()
    {
        if ((Customer != null))
        {
            return await Task.Run(GetItems_Action);
            //return await Task.Run(() => Current.ApplicationService.Schedule_Appointments_GetItems_By_Relation(Customer.Relation_ID));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and adding the next lines to allow adjustment from the view.

```
public Action Add_Action;
public Action<object> Edit_Action;
public Func<object, Task> Delete_Action;
public Func<Task<object>> GetItems_Action;
```